# FatalErrorException in SecureRandom.php line 27: Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\random_bytes()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, components, fatal-error

I have update my composer.
But get this error
I using larvel 5.0 .
Php 5.5 .
, please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**random_bytes()** function was added in **PHP7** so you need to upgrade PHP version you're using or install **paragonie/random_compat** package that provides this function for older versions of PHP - https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat.